# How to select C++ calling convention for a class / block / scope?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'd like to take advantage of the **vectorcall** convention (or **regcall**, etc. depending on the compiler), but for sake of 3rd party libraries it's not really possible to enable this convention as default for the entire project. Adding keywords to all functions / methods of a gigantic project doesn't seem like a very good idea either.

Is there a way to select a default calling convention to a class? Or perhaps a block, something similar to #pragma pack(push/pop)". Or just anything :).

Comment: What compiler/toolchain are you using?

Comment: I think the compiler can optimize the calling convention if necessary.

Comment: That's a bit of a problem - I'm on Windows & OSX and need stuff to work on MSVC, Intel and LLVM-Clang, all of them.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [2013 MSDN blog about vectorcall](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/07/11/introducing-vector-calling-convention/) it can be activated in Visual Studio via the /Gv compiler switch.

So perhaps a possible answer might be to place the code/classes that you want to use `vectorcall` into separate libraries from the code that should use standard calling conventions.

Those libraries can then be built with the appropriate compiler switch.

Comment: That would make things very complex in the context of a huge project. Plus when calling these libraries the vectorcall would need to be explicit anyways. If we assume there would be a "net" of classes/methods calling each other, this wouldn't really be an option.

Comment: If your shared library is built with `/Gv` then your clients need to build with `/Gv` or you have to instrument all function declarations in all your headers with `__vectorcall`. At which point you don't need `/Gv` anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - the exported functions is possible to set as __cdecl, there are only a few of them. The problem is the gazillions of imports from things like zlib, pnglib and others very less known, which unfortunately often just don't like having the vectorcall set by default for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

I would use something similar to an idiom: [Inline Guard Macro](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Inline_Guard_Macro)

So in this case:

```
#define CALL_CONVENTION vectorcall
```

This can be defined depending on other defines.

Then all your functions can look like this:

```
void CALL_CONVENTION func()
{ ... }
```

Comment: Yes of course, but I don't want to set it to every one of the thousands of the functions... hence my post.

Comment: This is only way to make it portable.

Comment: Well, you are not really answering my question - I can do it the way you said and I can do it via command line, but I want to set it for an entire class / scope or just some block, so I don't need to repeat it every time and at the same time not have it default for all functions/methods.